# How to calculate difference between times

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, time

How to calculate the difference in time in minutes? I used 2 templates T1 and T2 to select the time and tried to use function but I couldn't do it

```
>**first clock**
        *T1*.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(  
                        MainActivity.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                t1h = hourOfDay;
                                t1m = minute;
                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar.set(0, 0, 0,t1h,t1m);
                        T1.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format( "hh-mm a", calendar));
                   }}, 12, 0, false);
                timePickerDialog.updateTime(t1h,t1m);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            } });
// **second clock**
        T2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       // similiar cod
// **try to canculate but i can't**
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm");
                double c,x,y;
                String S3 = T1.getText().toString();
                String S4 = T2.getText().toString();
                x = Double.parseDouble(S3);
                y = Double.parseDouble(S4);
                c = y - x;
                String S = Double.toString(c);
                sr.setText(S);
            }    });  }}
```

https://github.com/Icefenix1996/time-calculate

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) to calculate the duration(difference) between two times. `Duration` is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(10, 20, 30);
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(11, 25, 40);
        Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1H5M10S
01:05:10
01:05:10
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PpVg83)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>